# Output the value from a random array key in php

Tags: php, arrays, random, key

Ok So I have had too much coffee and my mind has crashed.

Im trying to find the value from a randomly generated array key.. How would I achieve this? I have tried a lot without success :(

```
$array (

 1 => 2,
 2 => 3

);

$arrayKey = print_r(array_rand($array,1));

$arrayValue = ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$array=array (
 1 => 2,
 2 => 3
);
$arrayKey = array_rand($array,1);
echo $array[$arrayKey];// "prints" 2 or 3
```

Comment: Ive tried doing this but instead creating a variable and it didn't work :/ - $arrayValue = $array[$arrayKey];

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I forgot to omit the "print_r"... Thanks a lot guys!